# How to roll back a parent changeset from a child branch in TFS?

Tags: tfs, branch, rollback, changeset

I have the following structure:

```
Branch ROOT - contains Changeset 1, Changeset 2
      Branch CHILD
```

**Using Source Control Explorer, what would be the easiest way to roll back the changeset 2 for the branch CHILD and at the same time leave the branch ROOT intact?**

When looking in the history of the branch CHILD, the history starts with the branching point, thus I cannot select the changeset 2 to roll it back.

By the way, I'm using TFS 2010.

Answer (score 1):

1. Rollback changeset 2 in ROOT.
2. Merge ROOT to CHILD.
3. "Rollback the Rollback" from Step #1 in ROOT.

Comment: Sounds good for one changeset, but it might get tricky if there are many changesets to rollback, and also other developers might grab the source from ROOT with some changesets rolled back. I hoped that there is some way to achieve this without touching the ROOT at all.

Comment: @Dylan Smith:   So this is the only way?  I'm not that happy about monkeying with the ROOT branch to influence the CHILD branch.  I've got two issues with this:  One, it adds history in ROOT that will be weird looking in the future.  Two, if I make a mistake I've now messed up ROOT and possibly even CHILD.

Comment: If you were using git there’s more options.